# Cannot get kernel crash dump saved and reboot

Tags: linux-kernel, crash, magic-sysrq, kdump

I need to get a crash dump of my linux kernel.

I am going to describe the scenario:

1. Hardware: Notebook Dell E5450.
2. Linux Distribution: Linux Mint 18.3 (Ubuntu 16.04).
3. SysRq: enabled by /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf.
4. Installed packages: linux-crashdump.
5. Grub2: added "crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M"
6. Kdump check: "kdump-config show" reports a working configuration.
7. File system: folder "/var/crash" exists.

When I press "Alt+PrnScr+C" the system freezes without reboot and does not save any dump into /var/crash. Same thing sending "echo c | sudo tee /proc/sysrq-trigger".

How could I fix this situation?

Thank you so much!

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/602486/why-is-linux-kdump-not-writing-to-var-crash Does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I configured NETCONSOLE to see what happened to my system. Thank you anyway!